# Jenkins seems to be taking too much memory in CentOS

Tags: jenkins

All the commands below are ran under the `root` user. In order to find out the PID of Jenkins, I ran the command like this.

```
#ps aux | grep jenkins
```

and with the PID I ran another one, which is

```
#pmap -x [PID]
```

Here's the result I got from the command.

```
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000       4       0       0 r-x-- java
0000000000600000       4       4       4 r---- java
0000000000601000       4       4       4 rw--- java
0000000000b3e000     312     216     216 rw---   [ anon ]
...
00007ffc29848000    1156      32      32 rw---   [ stack ]
00007ffc29976000       8       4       0 r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000       4       0       0 r-x--   [ anon ]
---------------- ------- ------- ------- 
total kB         10027288 1172504 1163812
```

So, Jenkins seems to be taking approximately 9.6 gigabytes. Currently there are around 35 items added in Jenkins, and only 8 out of them are built periodically on a daily basis. I do believe that there should not be any reason for Jenkins to consume this huge memory, so I now have the following 3 doubts:

1. That I figured out the memory usage in a wrong way (the pmap command did not deliver the right figure),
2. or there is really a problem with the Jenkins configuration
3. or it is just natural to consume this amount with that number of items

Any Jenkins experts out there? I do need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Jenkins expert, but I have some knowledge for Linux memory management and Java applications.

You said `Jenkins seems to be taking approximately 9.6 gigabytes.`, it's not correct an aspect of memory consumption.
The 9.6GiB( Check the your jenkin's java heap memory option ) memory is virtual memory that just was estimated from OS, RSS(Resident Set Size) is real memory usage.
So my answer is similar with it, `it is just natural to consume this amount with that number of items`.

I hope this will help you.